# Eclipse content assist without library

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

When I begin typing "butt" for "button", the content assist recommends a Button - that is right and I want it like this.
[see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVCN9.png)
But when I press enter, it inserts "java.awt.Button"
[see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7f1I.png)

How do I tell the assist to insert only "Button"?

Answer (score 0):

Your Eclipse IDE may not be properly configured for JavaFX which could prevent autocomplete from finding JavaFX's classes. The solution is likely to [update Eclipse IDE's access rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48973377/10226142), otherwise you may be interested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17580642/10226142) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49545451/10226142). Read below for further details.

You already import JavaFX's `Button` whereas the autocomplete proposes AWT's `Button` (see the `java.awt` on the right of the proposal). To make sure AWT's Button is not mistaken for JavaFX's one [its fully qualified name has to be use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079823/importing-two-classes-with-same-name-how-to-handle) — hence `java.awt.Button`. 
The real issue is that your content assist should also propose the `javafx.scene.control.Button` class, and that should be solved by configuring access rules as described in the first answer I linked.